# How to pass textfield data from ajax action in Struts 2 to original calling .jsp?

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, dojo

I'm not sure if that title is phrased correctly. Let me explain what I'm trying to do:

I have a file **new.jsp** with a form

```
<s:form id="newdep" name="newdep" theme="simple" action="submitForm" >
```

In this form is a select box:

```
<s:select list="apps" name="app" onchange="javascript:show_details();return false;" />
```

I'm using Dojo for ajax, and it's calling:

```
function show_details() {
    dojo.event.topic.publish("show_detail");
}
```

Also within this form I have :

```
<s:url id="d_url" action="showComp" /> 
<sx:div id="details" href="%{d_url}" listenTopics="show_detail" formId="newdep" showLoadingText=""/>
```

This calls `comp.jsp` on the fly with action `showComp`.

It display a number of textfields depending on the selection made in the "app" select box.

More specifically, once an app is selected, a hashmap `lstList` is created specific to that app (within `CompAction` - the action class for `showComp`) and displayed like so:

```
<s:iterator value="lstList">   
  <s:property value="key" />   
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <s:textfield name="value" value=""/> <!-- LINE I'M ASKING ABOUT -->
  <s:iterator value="value">     
    <br> 
  </s:iterator>
```

I've highlighted the textfield line because I don't think that's right. Basically, what I want to do is:

1. Have the user select an app from the drop down. (done)
2. `comp.jsp` is called and displays relevant label from hashmap + text field for each. (done)
3. User's entries into textfields are saved into hashmap when user clicks submit button (**doesn't work**)

I should mention at this point that after clicking submit the user is sent to `results.jsp`.

From this page I can easily access the data from the larger action class, `FormAction`. But I do not know how to access data (such as the hashmap) from `CompAction` (once again, the action class for the ajax action).

So, 4. Access hashmap data from results.jsp (**also doesn't work**)

My natural instinct was to use

```
<s:property value="%{lstList}" />
```

in `results.jsp` but no luck. I'm pretty new to struts but I'm trying my best to get a good feel for it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got you, but I will try to help. Taking a look to your `comp.jsp`, specially the line you have highlighted, it looks like you are are creating many inputs with the same name: "value" (because in `<s:textfield />` "value" is not acting as a variable, but as a simple name), one for each hashmap entry. I recommend you to take a look to the HTML code generate by `comp.jsp`. That said, if you have many fields with the same name, all the values of these fields will be mapped as a `String[]` in the action. So if you define a `String[]` in your action, you will get all the values.

OK, but you need also the name, I mean, you need to get in the action name-value for all your fields. For that, first, you should change your `comp.jsp`, forget about `<s:textfield ...`/> and generate the html code by yourserlf:

```
<s:iterator value="lstList">   
    <input type="text" name="_<s:property value="key" />" value="<s:property value="value" />" />    
    <br> 
</s:iterator>
```

Notice that all fields names start with "_".

Then, in the action, you should access to the request and get a list of all the parameters in the request, take those that starts with "_" and build the hashmap with its names and values by yourself.